# inner model notion

Tags: set-theory

I am confused by some notation, and perhaps theory, associated with inner models.  I have seen an inner model, $M$, of $N$ defined by the formula, $F$, as given by the pair: $M = \langle n, e^{m \times m}\rangle $, where $m = \{a \in n : \langle n, e\rangle \models F(a) \}$.

My question is: how does $\{a \in n : \langle n, e\rangle \models F(a) \}$ differs from $m = \{a \in n : F(a) \}$?

Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $M$ is transitive then $M\models F(a)$ is equivalent to $F^M(a)$, where $F^M$ is a formula that acquired by substituting every quantifier to its bounded form by $n$ (e.g. replace $\forall x$ to $\forall x\in n$.) If our $F$ have no quantifier then they are equivalent.

However, $F^M(a)$ and $F(a)$ are not equivalent in general even if $a$ is in $n$. If $V$ is a model of ZFC and $V[G]$ is a forcing extension obtained by adding $\aleph_1$ Cohen reals (so $\aleph_1^V$ is countable in $V[G]$.) If the predicate $F(x)$ states "$x$ is uncountable", then $F^V(\aleph_1^V)$ holds but $F^{V[G]}(\aleph_1^V)$ fails, though $\aleph_1^V$ is in $V$.

Comment: Thanks!  I don't know anything about forcing though.  Is there a counterexample that doesn't rely on it?

Comment: Actually, maybe the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem suffices for a counterexample?  Let F be "is uncountable".  Then there are sets in countable models that satisfy "is uncountable", but they are countable (in V).

Comment: @davidp Löwenheim-Skolem might works, but your direction seems not to give an inner model. Models obtained from Löwenheim-Skolem generally have *distorted* membership relation. You might know the definition of inner model, which says that the membership relation of the model coincides with that of the universe $V$.

Comment: I will try to find a example does not rely on the forcing, but I have no idea at the present.

Comment: Sorry -- you're right.

Comment: OK, thanks again.

Comment: @davidp If we accept the existence of a *countable* transitive model $M$ of ZFC, then it is an another counterexample. If $F$ is same as the my answer, then $F^M(x)$ holds for some countable (in $V$) ordinals, but no countable ordinal satisfies $F(x)$. Understanding the counterexample is quite related to that of the [Skolem's paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem%27s_paradox).

Comment: More precisely, if $x$ is $\omega_1^M$ (first uncountable ordinal in $M$) then it is countable ordinal in $V$ (because $M$ is countable and $\omega_1^M\subseteq M$) but *uncountable in $M$*. Thus $\lnot F(\omega_1^M)$ and $F^M(\omega_1^M)$.

Comment: Got it -- thanks very much!

Comment: Another example : Let$ N=(n,\in)$ be a countably infinite transitive model that satisfies the power set axiom  and with $\omega=(\omega)^N \in n.$  Let $F(a)\iff a=P(\omega)$ (the power set of $\omega$).  Then $\{a\in n: F(a)\}=\phi$  but $\{a\in n :F^N (a)\}=\{b\}$ where  $b= \{c \in n: c\subset \omega \}\supset  \omega.$

Comment: @HanulJeon It suffices to take a transitive, countable model of a "sufficienlty large" fragment of $\operatorname{ZFC}$ and those exist.